# Add iAds without affecting previous users

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I want to know if there is a good way to implement ads into my app without affecting users that have already downloaded it. For my next update, I want to add iAds with an IAP option to remove them. The problem is, I don't want ads to show up on users whom are already using the app.

I am thinking of using a BOOL stored in NSUserDefaults to keep track of whether to display ads or not. I want new users to download the app with this flag set to display ads, but users who are updating to have this flag set to as if they had already purchased this new IAP. How and what is a good way to go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you stored anything in NSUserDefaults in an existing version?

Comment: note that NSUserDefaults does not survive if the app is uninstalled, while a record in the KeyChain does.

Comment: I was asking because in that case it would be easy for you to find out if previous version was installed allready or not. You could try releasing intermediate version (without iAds) writing BOOL to NO and then the 'real' new version. But it takes time. And magma has a good point there.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will look into KeyChain or iCloud to store the BOOL. And thanks for that idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No real way of doing it.
Assuming you're not using the UDID and sending it over to some server to check that is (this won't solve multiple devices anyway).
You should probably release a new version now without iAds, save in the preferences (or better yet, iCloud) that these users are good to go without iAds and after a while, release your iAd version, checking that preference.
Of course, if the user removes the app or installs on a new device - your preferences are lost and he gets iAds.
That's where iCloud comes in handy but you may want to use iCloud differently, so there is no clean solution for this.
Also note that users that didn't upgrade will get iAds anyway- just like NSPostWhenIdle said.

Comment: Another condition to think about is wether or not the user skips the first update, and downloads the second one.